# Macro para imprimir informe "n" veces (Access)

Tags: ms-access, macros, vb

Antes de nada, agradecer que dediquéis vuestro tiempo en leer y/o responder mi post. Soy nueva en foros así como en la utilización de Access.

Estoy elaborando una bbdd que me permita imprimir etiquetas de productos, en función de un nº de albarán.

He creado una macro que abre el informe e imprime las etiquetas, pero 1 unidad de cada.

La macro convertido a VB es:

```
'------------------------------------------------------------
' Imprimir_Etiqueta_05
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Function Imprimir_Etiqueta_05()
On Error GoTo Imprimir_Etiqueta_05_Err

DoCmd.OpenReport "Etiquetas Consulta Albarán", acViewNormal, "", "", acNormal


Imprimir_Etiqueta_05_Exit:
Exit Function

Imprimir_Etiqueta_05_Err:
MsgBox Error$
Resume Imprimir_Etiqueta_05_Exit

End Function
```

Necesito que se impriman "n" etiquetas, en función de la cantidad pedida en cada línea del albarán. Ese dato lo tengo en la consulta "Consulta Albaran", en un campo que se llama "CantidadPedida"

He estado mirando los bucles que existen, pero no sé muy bien cuál se adapta a mis necesidades, ni como ponerlo.

Agradecería muchísimo que me pudierais echar una mano.

Saludos

Comment: Hola. La cantidad N de etiquetas está en una consulta. Pero para mirar ese dato, necesitas saber qué registro es. Con un DLOOKUP podrías mirar ese dato, guardarlo en una variable, y ejecutar tu macro de impresión tantas veces como indique la variable. Mira https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/access.application.dlookup

Comment: Y el bucle que necesitas en este caso es un `FOR..NEXT`. Mira https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve un problema similar hace un tiempo y lo resolví de la siguiente forma:
1. Crear una tabla con números del 1 al máximo número de albaranes que puedas tener (ej: Tabla [Numeros] campo ID autonumérico de 1 a 200
2. El report que tienes habría que modificarlo para vincularlo con la tabla [Numeros] y que la condición de unión sea Numeros.ID <= [Consulta Albaran].CantidadPedida
3. La función que te ha creado habría que modificarla para que acepte como parámetro el número de Albarán:

```
'------------------------------------------------------------
' Imprimir_Etiqueta_05
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Function Imprimir_Etiqueta_05(NoAlbaran AS STRING)
On Error GoTo Imprimir_Etiqueta_05_Err

DoCmd.OpenReport "Etiquetas Consulta Albarán", acViewNormal, "", "<NoAlbaran>="""+NoAlbaran+"""", acNormal


Imprimir_Etiqueta_05_Exit:
Exit Function

Imprimir_Etiqueta_05_Err:
MsgBox Error$
Resume Imprimir_Etiqueta_05_Exit

End Function
```

No puedo reproducirlo pero debería ser algo así. Suerte y ya nos dirás que tal te funciona.